# HDMI to DVI via cable

Tags: hdmi, dvi

Is it possible to connect my laptop via HDMI output to external monitor with DVI input. I know it is not possible to plug it in VGA output (from HDMI) so I am interested what about DVI. I can't find any reliable answer on google.

Comment: DVI and HDMI are electrically compatible (for video), you just need a simple HDMI->DVI cable or adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

[Click here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=hdmi%20to%20dvi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=bpo5U-PTM8jGgATzsYHYCA) for possible solutions. As you can see from the results, there are solutions that are managed with a single cable, as well as solutions that provide a simple adapter, which allows you to use an existing cable.

Choose as needed.

Comment: yes, but [this](https://www.google.at/search?q=hdmi+to+vga&oq=hdmi+to+vga&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2096j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) exists also and it is not possible to use it.

Comment: @DusanMalic Why isn't it possible to use an HDMI to VGA converter?